# VBA Macro for copying visible data in specific columns without header to defined columns in new file and adding number to new column to all rows

Tags: excel, vba, macos

First, I want to apologize for the terrible title of the query, but I couldn't think of a better way to describe it.

I'm a complete novice when it comes to VBA (basic VBA training was 4 days ago). I have thought of a macro that would be useful at work, but I just don't know how to put the "components" together. Excel which we use is Microsoft 365.

I have a large excel file with macros (11MB), I need to copy certain, filtered columns from this file from a sheet into another file.

[image]

Based on column B and Q, I have filtered the data I need to copy.
I need to copy only visible rows in the columns without header into a file (txt "table" - it means a txt file that opens in excel) *0_import.txt* (this file is stored elsewhere than original file) as follows:

- column I into column A
- column G into column B
- column T into columns C and D

I don't need to copy the whole columns I and T (they contain pre-generated data), but only until the row where column G ends. This means that if the last record in column G is on row 616, I need the data to be copied to row 616 for columns I and T as well even if it is not the last row on which the data in those columns are.

And I need to add the number 5 into column E.

But first I need to delete the entire file to ensure that no old data remains, and finally I need to save the file *0_import.txt*.

[image]

Since I'm a complete beginner, I've have only code for copying visible cells in column G.

```
Sub Copy_to_new_file()
'
' Copy_to_new_file Macro
' Copy only visible rows in columns G, I, T from this file into new file and add no. 5 into last column.
'
' Shortcut key: Ctrl+Shift+S
'
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate ' Set the worksheet that contains data as active

' Select only visible cells in column G (sadly with header, which I don't want)
Range("G1", Range("G1").End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy

' Set the workbook and the worksheet where to copy data
Dim end_file As Workbook
Dim ws_end As Worksheet

Set end_file = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user_name\Documents\0_import.txt")

Set ws_end = Worksheets("0_import")

ws_end.Range("B1").Select ' Set column where to copy visible data from column G in original file
ws_end.Paste

' Delete header from new file (because I don't now how to copy column without it)
ws_end.Range("A1:E1").Select  
Selection.EntireRow.Delete

' Save new file
end_file.Save  

End Sub
```

But I can't figure out how to copy other visible data in columns I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to write code that works the way I need it to.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyOnlyVisibleRowsInColumnsG_I_T()
'
' CopyOnlyVisibleRowsInColumnsG_I_T Macro
' Copy only visible rows in columns G, I, T into new file and add no. 5 into last column.
'
' Shortcut key: Ctrl+Shift+I
'
    Dim startWs As Worksheet
    Dim endFile As Workbook
    Dim endWs As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowColB As Long
    Dim lastRowColG As Long
    
    Set startWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set endFile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user_name\OneDrive\Documents\0_import.txt")
    
    Set endWs = Worksheets("0_import")
    
    'clear all content in target workbook
    Cells.ClearContents
    
    'set last row in column G 
    lastRowColG = startWs.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    
    startWs.Range("G1:G" & lastRowColG).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=endWs.Range("B:B")
    startWs.Range("I1:I" & lastRowColG).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=endWs.Range("A:A")
    startWs.Range("T1:T" & lastRowColG).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=endWs.Range("C:C")
    startWs.Range("T1:T" & lastRowColG).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=endWs.Range("D:D")
    
    'convert text format to date format for columns C and D
    endWs.Range("C:C, D:D").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"

    'delete header from new worksheet
    endWs.Range("A1:E1").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    
    'adds 5 to column E according to the number of rows in column B
    lastRowColB = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("E1:E" & lastRowColB).Value = 5
    
    'save new file
    endFile.Save
End Sub
```

The only thing that doesn't work is the keyboard shortcut but that's for a new query.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. I added some comments, but if you have more questions feel free to ask. This saves the txt file to "C:\Users\<your user>\Documents"

```
Private Sub copyToFile()
    Dim x As Integer
    
    ' Set the worksheet that contains your data as active
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    
    'Create two dimensional array (a table) to contain the data you want to copy
    Dim dataToCopy() As String
    ReDim dataToCopy(2, 0)
    
    ' Set numrows = number of rows of data in column G
    NumRows = Range("G1", Range("G1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    
    ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times
    For x = 1 To NumRows
        ' Filter row by columns B and Q to be extracted
        If Range("B" & x).Value = "def" And Range("Q" & x).Value = "" Then
            ' Resize the array since you found an additional row you want to copy
            ReDim Preserve dataToCopy(2, UBound(dataToCopy, 2) - LBound(dataToCopy, 1) + 1)
            ' Copy column I
            dataToCopy(0, UBound(dataToCopy, 2)) = Range("I" & x).Value
            ' Copy column G
            dataToCopy(1, UBound(dataToCopy, 2)) = Range("G" & x).Value
            ' Copy column T
            dataToCopy(2, UBound(dataToCopy, 2)) = Range("T" & x).Value
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Create a file handle and define path where to save the txt file
    Dim handle As Long
    handle = FreeFile
    Open Application.DefaultFilePath & "\Whatever.txt" For Output As #handle
    
    For y = 1 To UBound(dataToCopy, 2)
        Print #handle, dataToCopy(0, y) & "," & dataToCopy(1, y) & "," & dataToCopy(2, y) & "," & dataToCopy(2, y) & "," & "5"
    Next
    
    Close #handle
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, this create new file in Documents folder but is's empty file. I changed just `Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate` to `Worksheets("Data sum").Activate`  because that's worksheet where my data are stored.

Comment: Last section 
`Dim handle As Long
handle = FreeFile
...` is completely alien for me. How do I set path to "C:\Users\user_name\differentFolder\0_import.txt"? 
Last question, why to set it as Private? Sorry for those questions but I'm really newbie in VBA.

Comment: 1. The file is probably empty since you need to define how you want to filter the lines you want to copy in this line:

`If Range("B" & x).Value = "def" And Range("Q" & x).Value = "" Then`

Comment: 2. Concerning `Dim handle As Long handle = FreeFile` you have to understand that in order for your code to understand the connection to another application or file it needs some kind of connection. Thats the "handle" variable here. And since we are creating "just some text file" we use the FreeFile file type.

Comment: 3. for the file path you can use a simple String. So instead of `Open Application.DefaultFilePath & "\Whatever.txt" For Output As #handle` you could use `Open "C:\some\other\path\0_import.txt" For Output As #handle`

Comment: 4. I set the sub to private since i don't know if your project uses other subs with the same name in some other module. Unless you are sure that you want this sub as it is everywhere in your project to behave the same and you dont have other implementations with the same name you can make it public too. To understand this better you should have a look at "Object-oriented programming (OOP)" and its 4 basic building blocks "Abstraction", "Encapsulation", "Inheritance" and "Polymorphism"

Comment: 2. and 3.  Thank you for clarification, FreeFile and # is really new for me and I had hard time to understand this.

Comment: 4. Ah, I see I don't have subs with same name so that's why I was so confused.

Comment: 1. Oh, I understand now. I had to describe my problem badly, because `If Range("B" & x).Value = "def" And Range("Q" & x).Value = "" Then` isn't what I need. I already have my data filtered, now i just need them copy to another file. I need to count `NumRows` like that 
`Range("G1", Range("G1").End(xlDown)).Select`
`Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select`

Comment: Add 1.  only I don't copy header at all. And Also I can't have any `","` between values. I need to "say" copy column I from original file into column A in new file.